# Structure for mysql database with access front-end

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access, vba, data-structures

I have a server that collects a lot of information. Right now there is a database for each month and a table for each day of the month. Usually there are about 200,000+ rows per day (about 150MB a table).

On another post, someone suggested I just use one table per month to make it easier to manipulate the data. This would not be hard since all the entries have a date\time stamp.

The problem is that we have to use an MS Access front-end and the data is not linked, but imported each day for revision. This has worked well with a VBA script that automatically connects to the right database & table.

```
sConnect = "ODBC;Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};" & _
  "SERVER=172.16.0.0;" & _
  "PORT=3306;" & _
  "DATABASE=" & "Mon" & dbMonth & ";" & _
  "USER=USER;" & _
  "PASSWORD=PASS;"

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "ODBC Database", _
  sConnect, acTable, "Data" & dbDay, "Revise", , True
```

Anyone have a suggestion for an quick & easy way to automatically import just the day's info from a database that has 6 million+ entries? Right now it takes about 20 seconds over the LAN to import one day's worth of data.

Thanks!

Comment: You will note that every answer has asked the same question, i.e., why you think you need to import it into a table instead of just linking to the original data source. One reason for not importing is that Jet/ACE has a 2GB limit on file size, and with 200K records per day, unless they are extremely narrow records (i.e., a handful of columns with compact data types), you could easily outrun the capacity of Jet/ACE to store that amount of data in not too long a period of time. Perhaps you've not properly indexed your tables in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am going to restructure the database, because I found out that Access has a "hidden" way to populate the filtering list from linked tables. In database options you can tell it to use ODBC for filter lists too. It is was hard to find & I didn't even think it could be done. Now I have a lot more options because I can just link the tables.

Thank for all those who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

One question that enters my mind is why are you separating your information off like this - why not simply time stamp the entries, and dump it all into one database to work against.  Much easier to keep track of, maintain, backup, and restore - then just write your VBA to fetch the appropriate records for your front-end to revise, pushing them back to the table within that one database once your revisions are through - perhaps checking a 'Revised' checkbox to indicate that these should NOT be pulled next time (if I am understanding the purpose correctly).

Another is why would you not want to link to the database, or at least a view of the database?

I am still a little new here, so perhaps there is larger concerns I am not seeing with my questions - and if so, I'd love to be enlightened as well.

Comment: I'm also very new to using mysql. The situation is a little complicated because we need to have the data imported into a table and not just linked. I am not sure how I would get records from only one day imported into an Access table. Perhaps I could link it instead of import and generate a query with VBA to make a new table, but that seems a bit complicated.

Comment: But the question is *WHY* you think you need it imported, and not just linked?

Comment: It is a little silly, the people who use the Access interface are not very good with computers and have become used to the feature of access that gives a checkbox list you see showing all the available values in a column when you are FILTERING a datasheet. The problem is that this is not available to my queries when I take the data from a linked table. It only works if it is an imported table. I thought there was no way to get around that problem without importing the data.

Comment: So, in other words, you're engineering your database around the Access UI? That seems backwards to me!

Answer (score 1):

I would put all data into a single table, create a link instead of importing and generate your query from VBA. Yes, it may be a bit complicated up front, but, in my opinion, the easiest to continue working with and maintain.

We have mixins of MySql, Access database, Access forms, VB6 and VB.Net. It is a pain to work with all of these technologies. I have done enough with the apps to know that a single table and re-linking is your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

I'd stick with one table in MySQL and add a timestamp field with a default of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, so that MySQL will auto-populate this timestamp field.

A simple query can then return one month's records, which you could append to a temp (?) table.

However...

> we need to have the data imported into
>   a table and not just linked

Are you sure you *really* need to do that? If you are processing each record further via vba, can you not include any additional info as extra fields in the original MySQL table?

Comment: Thanks, maxhugen. I explained the situation in a comment above. Perhaps you have a suggestion.

Comment: I use a main form, with a continuous forms subform, and a separate subform with Filter fields. These Filter fields can be combos, populated with the appropriate values. The actual [Filter] button can then either modify the original SQL with a WHERE clause, or use the Filter property of the continuous forms subform. HTH.